# Publish Azure Webapp - Compilation Error

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Ive published my Website to Azure as an WebApp. If i call the url in the Browser i got the following exception:

```
Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -532462766.

Details >> D:\Windows\system32>D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\roslyn\csc.exe ..
```

The Eventviewer gave much more detail:

```
Event code: 3007
Event message: A compilation error has occurred.
Event time: 3/8/2016 1:35:14 PM
Event time (UTC): 3/8/2016 1:35:14 PM
Event ID: 477178e2e625406e9be094df085f6bc9
Event sequence: 3
Event occurrence: 1
Event detail code: 0

Application information:
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/540489099/ROOT-1-131019177071229326
Trust level: Full
Application Virtual Path: /
Application Path: D:\home\site\wwwroot\
Machine name: RD000D3AB25B42

Process information:
Process ID: 14752
Process name: w3wp.exe
Account name: IIS APPPOOL\mySite

Exception information:
Exception type: HttpCompileException
Exception message: External component has thrown an exception. at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() at System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod() at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)


Request information:
Request URL: http://mySite.azurewebsites.net/
Request path: /
User host address: ...
User: 
Is authenticated: False
Authentication Type: 
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\mySite

Thread information:
Thread ID: 9
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\mySite
Is impersonating: False
Stack trace: at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() at System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod() at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)

Custom event details:
```

#### I tryed to

- rebuild the project and re-publish
- restarted the site via azure portal
- scaled the site up and down to ensure a really "fresh" state

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: _Remove additional files at destination_ is this selected or Do you remove files before deployement? If you don't, try with it. If it doesn't work, try to kill your process on https://xxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/.

Comment: Remove additional files at destination fixes problem! Thx! Feel free to post this as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select *Remove additional files at destination* on Settings>File Publish options. Because of some old dlls can prevent to application start (versioning issue etc.).

Comment: I already had this setting checked. Today my server give the same error, can this be prevented in an other way? After two restarts it works again..

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I managed to solve it. First, open your website root using FTP client and remove all the files. Next publish your project on File System and then copy it back to the website root using FTP Client.